# UICollectionView showing scroll indicator for every section (header zIndex broken)

Tags: ios, xcode9-beta

When scrolling through my `UICollectionView` it's showing more than one scroll indicator. I've noticed there is a one for every section in the collection. See screenshot displaying three at the same time:

[image]

Anyone experienced same issue? I am using Xcode 9 beta 3. My collectionview setup is quite common:

```
private let formCollectionView: UICollectionView = {
        let collectionViewLayout = UICollectionViewFlowLayout()
        collectionViewLayout.minimumLineSpacing = 0
        collectionViewLayout.minimumInteritemSpacing = 0
        let collectionView = UICollectionView(frame: .zero, collectionViewLayout: collectionViewLayout)
        collectionView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        collectionView.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
        return collectionView
}()
```

**Edit 10/16/2017**

Even Twitter seems having this issue:

[image]

Comment: Bizarre. It's hard to tell from the screenshot, but are they really scroll indicators, and not just some other view that's getting cut off?

Comment: They are definitely scroll indicators since I can get rid of them by setting `showsVerticalScrollIndicator` to false. While I am scrolling they are appearing and decreasing their height until they disappear. And no, I am not smoking any hash.

Comment: no updates on this? Does this occur for "all" iOS-versions?

Comment: As far as I know it's just latest iOS 11 problem.

Comment: The footer / header view seems to be overlapping the scrollbar, which appears to have a lower zPosition than the section headers / footers.

Answer (score 27):

you can fix this problem in delegate method.as in the following example

**Objective-C**

```
- (void)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView willDisplaySupplementaryView:(UICollectionReusableView *)view forElementKind:(NSString *)elementKind atIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
    {
        if (@available(iOS 11.0, *)) {
            if ([elementKind isEqualToString:UICollectionElementKindSectionHeader]) {
                view.layer.zPosition = 0;
            }
        }
    }
```

**Swift**

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, willDisplaySupplementaryView view: UICollectionReusableView, forElementKind elementKind: String, at indexPath: IndexPath) {
    if elementKind == UICollectionView.elementKindSectionHeader {
        view.layer.zPosition = 0
    }
}
```

Comment: This solution seems to be working more consistently than others.

Comment: It's not about consistency, this is in fact the correct collection. Those aren't multiple scrollbars, it's the same scrollbar being overlapped by a section header view, which appears to have a higher zPosition than the rest of the child views but lower than the scrollbar indicator. The scrollbar is overlapped by an opaque header view in the screenshot above, making it look as though there are multiple scrollbar indicators.

Answer (score 3):

Ok, so first of all there is a [radar](http://www.openradar.me/34308893) already.

There is a proposed workaround. I was partially successful with doing this crap inside my `UICollectionReusableView` subclass.

```
override func apply(_ layoutAttributes: UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes) {
    super.apply(layoutAttributes)
    DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: DispatchTime.now() + 0.01) {
        self.layer.zPosition = 0
    }
}
```

I am saying partially because if you have a little bit longer `UICollectionView` it's still corrupted for some headers. Most of them are ok though. So it depends on your situation. Hopefully that radar will be addressed soon.

Comment: There is a reliable [workaround](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46903209/uicollectionview-fails-to-honour-zposition-and-zindex-ios-11-only/)

Answer (score 1):

That are not multiple scroll indicators. The z index of the header views is higher than that of the scroll indicator view.

Edit: found something more interesting, if you run the view debugger the scroll indicator is positioned above the headers... something weird is going on.

Comment: Interesting. Because I also have a bug in my collectionview that when editing (reordering/drag&drop) cells header view is covering a dragged cell. I am not setting a zIndex anywhere though. I am not using custom layout, just `referenceSizeForHeaderInSection` and `sizeForItemAt` for device orientation adaption. Everything is working just fine in iOS 10. Have you experienced this bug as well? Don't you have some hint how to fix?

Comment: Just found related [radar](http://www.openradar.me/34308893). No luck with proposed workaround though.

Answer (score 0):

There is a simple method to fix this problem. In your section header view Class, you can override method `layoutSubviews`, and write:

```
- (void)layoutSubviews {
    [super layoutSubviews];
    self.layer.zPosition = 0;
}
```

Because, before iOS11, the section view's layer zPosition value is default 0, but in iOS11, this default value is 1.

Comment: It still stays broken for me. Not all headers but there are some. Fix rate seems very similar to already proposed `apply(_:)` overriding :(

Comment: eee...may be you should use 'Debug View Hierarchy' Or 'Reveal' check whether the section header view layer zPosition is Actually be set 0.