# UICollectionView fails to honour zPosition and zIndex - iOS 11 only

Tags: uicollectionview, ios11

I try to find a workaround for this radar: http://www.openradar.me/34308893

Currently in my `- (void)applyLayoutAttributes:(UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes *)layoutAttributes` I'm doing the following:

```
dispatch_after(dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, NSEC_PER_MSEC * 50), dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
    self.layer.zPosition = 0;
});
```

But no matter how many `NSEC_PER_MSEC` I enter it doesn't work quite right, the scrolling indicator sometimes hides behind the headers, especially when ne headers appear. Is there another/better approach?

Comment: Maybe this solution will help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46518725/mapkit-mkmapview-zposition-does-not-work-anymore-on-ios11

Answer (score 9):

I had a similar problem where a header view in a UICollectionView was getting rendered above another view that had it's `zIndex` set > 0 in a custom `UICollectionViewFlowLayout`.

The answer for me was to set the header view layer's `zPosition` in `willDisplaySupplementaryView`:

```
override public func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView,
                                    willDisplaySupplementaryView view: UICollectionReusableView,
                                    forElementKind elementKind: String,
                                    at indexPath: IndexPath) {
    if elementKind == UICollectionView.elementKindSectionHeader && type(of: view) == CollectionViewSectionHeaderView.self {
      view.layer.zPosition = -1
    }
  }
```

iOS11 doesn't seem to honor z-indexes in `UICollectionViewFlowLayout` subclasses.

Comment: Thanks - I have updated my [radar](http://www.openradar.me/radar?id=5530597493571584) with your workaround, it's a better solution than using unreliable delay timers.

Comment: Unfortunately still not 100% perfect when scrolling fast. Also its no-go when having the floating sections - it will make a section pinned beneath its cells :(

Comment: Looks like this is still happening in iOS 12.

Comment: Still in iOS 14