# What change my layer position

Tags: ios, objective-c, layer, z-order

I have a TDHomeCollectionHeaderView, I set zposition=-999 in its `initWithFrame`.but I found the zPosition is 1 in drawRect.What happened? What change my layer position? TDHomeCollectionHeaderView is a SupplementaryView of UICollectionView.

```
    - (instancetype)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
  {
      self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    if (self) {
        [self addSubview:self.imageView];
        [self addSubview:self.iconView];
        [self addSubview:self.label];
        self.userInteractionEnabled = NO;
        self.layer.zPosition = -999;
    }
    return self;
  }

   -(void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect
  {
   //here zposition is 1
    NSLog(@"TDHomeCollectionHeaderView %f",self.layer.zPosition);
  }
```

Comment: //here zposition is 0
    NSLog(@"TDHomeCollectionHeaderView %f",self.layer.zPosition);

Comment: @JRB here zposition is 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is a radar http://www.openradar.me/34308893.  A better around is suggested in this StackOverflow reply:"Set the header view layer's zPosition in willDisplaySupplementaryView".([UICollectionView fails to honour zPosition and zIndex - iOS 11 only](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46903209/uicollectionview-fails-to-honour-zposition-and-zindex-ios-11-only))